# Multiple divs selected with jQuery, select one with #

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

[Here](http://www.giaule.it/wordpress/?page_id=129) I have some images, when you click one image a div appears. When you click another images the related div appears and the previoulsy loaded one disappears. What I'd like to have is the possibility to load the page with a specific div already loaded. So if I visit
http://www.giaule.it/wordpress/?page_id=129#architettonici I'd like the last one appear (#architettonici is the ID that triggers the last one). Or http://www.giaule.it/wordpress/?page_id=129##edifici should "open" the first div.

Ca you help me? Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been waiting over 4 minutes and your page didn't opened yet, but probably I got what you need.

You might need to use this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (!!window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        /* Your code to open the div */   
    }
}
```

Where the `var hash` is simply the hashlink pulled out from the URL, so you can target a div by ID for instance.

**EDIT**

Here's your revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9n2tA/1 and here's the working demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9n2tA/1/show/light/#edifici

Comment: So I should wrap my function showContent(content) in this snippet, right? :) Sorry for the long loading time..

Comment: I don't know what that function does, (I still cannot open the URLs) but very probably you need to put in that function if it does open the divs

Comment: I tried but the function doesn't open the divs anymore. I created a fiddle with my code (hopefully it will load) :)
http://jsfiddle.net/9n2tA/

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense! You have already an onload function so you have to put the code inside there. Here's your revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9n2tA/1/ and here's the working demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9n2tA/1/show/light/#edifici